# Strange ip's on firewall log

Tags: router, firewall

Check the image on my routers firewall log i can see traffic from strange ip address to my public address. what are these? i just setup this router few hours ago, am i been hacked or part of DoS attack?

[image: log]

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Those are normal IPs. My guess: Some infected hosts scanning for other hosts to infect and some (D)DOS traffic. Absolutely normal. If you also copied the destination Port we would be able to tell more.

Answer (score 2):

dear i'm suffering same problem as you ***exactly*** with my firewall so after a lot of researches i found a very good article speak about that in the next link

As Brian Krebs explains -- [Who's Scanning Your Network (A: Everyone)](http://krebsonsecurity.com/2015/05/whos-scanning-your-network-a-everyone/), this is simply the fact of life of *anything* connected to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like you are victim of an scanning proccess, if you can see, all the traces are UDP, that is an port open discovery proccess.

Comment: Victim is a hard word. If you don't want to be scanned keep away from the Internet.